# How to use Bluetooth PAN profile through External Accessory Framework

Tags: ios, bluetooth, external-accessory

I am trying to create a Bluetooth Personal Area Network (PAN) from within my iOS application. Based on the [MFi FAQ](https://mfi.apple.com/MFiWeb/getFAQ.action#1-2) and [HT3647](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT3647), it should be possible to talk to other (non iOS devices) using Bluetooth PAN.
However, I cannot find any further information on how to accomplish this on iOS.

- Is it possible to create a Bluetooth PAN via the External Accessory framework?
- Are there other ways to talk to Bluetooth (not BLE) devices?

Comment: @deskop Any luck with this?  I'm also interested in the answer

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you don't have (and should not require) direct access to any legacy (non BLE) profiles from your iOS apps.

PAN (and other Bluetooth profiles and services, such as A2DP for audio) is available only in case when iOS itself pairs to the device and creates PAN network completely without your knowledge. After that PAN should be available for use to your app without doing anything Bluetooth related. But the problem here is to know *how* iOS itself is using PAN, and currently it seems that it is being used for tethering only and nothing more. So, I guess you're out of luck if you hoped to use PAN for your own specific needs.

External Accessory Framework is another thing, it is meant for MFi certified devices that want to implement custom protocols, for example, a replacement for serial protocol which is not available on iOS (by Apple's intentional decision - to prevent custom communications with uncertified devices).